# How to write definition in box and remark in sidebar

Tags: boxes, lstdefinestyle

I've to write definition, lemma  in box and remark in sidebar like this photo.
[image]

Comment: What is the side bar here? Looks something for `tcolorbox` or `bclogo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like framed.sty does pretty much most of what you want.
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed?lang=en